# How to refresh the gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am a newbie in using asp.net, I am getting a problem on how to refresh the `GridView` after the data is updated but it seems it's not working on my others pages. I have same code when I updated the supplier info and then the `GridView1.Databind()` is working but when I try to use this again on my other pages it doesn't work. Can you give an idea why is this happens?

Here is my code:

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE ProductTable SET ProductCode = ('" & lbl_productcode.Text & "'), ProductName = ('" & txt_prodname.Text & "'),ProductCategory =('" & lbl_category.Text & "'),Price =('" & txt_price.Text & "'), Quantity=('" & txt_qty.Text & "'), CategoryID=('" & lbl_catid.Text & "') WHERE ProductCategory = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
        cmd.Connection.Open()

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Connection.Close()
        MsgBox("RECORD UPDATED", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        GridView1.DataBind()
        Call clear()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Since I'm working mostly with *enterprise Java* and *mobile applications*, I'm not so much familiar with asp.net though just to say since asp.net supports server controls, there shouldn't be a need to refresh `GridView` as you say and what do you mean *"on my other pages it doesn't work"**? I seriously don't get what you want to say and what exactly your query is.

Comment: Arrgh! [Little Bobby Tables](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png) detected!

Answer (score 1):

I do not see anywhere in your code where you actually set the `DataSource` of your `GridView` before you `DataBind()` it. Check it out!

UPDATE:

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE ProductTable SET ProductCode = ('" & lbl_productcode.Text & "'), ProductName = ('" & txt_prodname.Text & "'),ProductCategory =('" & lbl_category.Text & "'),Price =('" & txt_price.Text & "'), Quantity=('" & txt_qty.Text & "'), CategoryID=('" & lbl_catid.Text & "') WHERE ProductCategory = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
    cmd.Connection.Open()

    Me.GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    GridView1.DataBind()

    cmd.Connection.Close()
    MsgBox("RECORD UPDATED", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

    Call clear()
End Sub
```

Good luck!

Comment: my datasource is cn... cn is declare on my module

Comment: @Carisle I have updated my code to demonstrate how your code should be. Please note that you were using ExecuteNonQuery, which should not be used for this specific case, so I used ExecuteReader instead, and used it as a datasource for your gridview. Good luck!